# Is there a way to install Android SDK offline for Samsung galaxy tab a 8.0 so I can use ADB to manage my root I'm running 5.0.2

Tags: adb, root-access, file-management

ADB Help For Samsung galaxy tab a 8.0 user

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you checked with our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) already?

Comment: I'd recommend you installe 'Minimal ADB and Fastboot' an easier Way to use ADB and much lightweight

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need Android SDK if all you want is ADB and fastboot - [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=385035244224386526) has you covered.